# How to calculate data transfer ifconfig per second in python?

Tags: python, time, ifconfig

I have script like this

```
import os
import time
os.chdir('/sys/class/net/wlan1/statistics')

while True:
    up = open('tx_bytes').read()
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'UP:',up
```

And the value is

```
UP: 2177453

UP: 2177539

UP: 2177789

UP: 2177990
```

How to find diferent value TX bytes after delay time.sleep and Befor delay time.sleep to get bandwidth Byte persecond?
Byte persecond = TXbytes_after_time_sleep - TXbytes_before_time_sleep
and the value can loopen no endless with while true.

Answer (score 1):

What is your worry so far?  YOu have a certain amount of innate overhead, since you have to return to the start of the file.  We can reduce it somewhat by getting rid of the superfluous **open** commands:

```
import time
old = 0
with open('/sys/class/net/wlan1/statistics/tx_bytes') as vol:
    while True:
        vol.seek(0)
        new = vol.read()
        time.sleep(1)
        print "UP:", new-old
        old = new
```

The **seek** command resets the file's "bookmark"" to byte 0, the start of the file.  It's faster than reopening the file, since it's merely an integer assignment to an object attribute.

Is this granularity good enough for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you did I guess.

It's quite rough and not very accurate but the same time spent reading the before is taken into account in reading the after so I guess it's fine.

```
with open('/sys/class/net/wlan1/statistics/tx_bytes') as myfile:
    before = myfile.read()
time.sleep(3)  # The longer this is the more accurate it will be on average.
with open('/sys/class/net/wlan1/statistics/tx_bytes') as myfile:
    after = myfile.read()
print((int(after)-int(before))/3)
```